# CSS3 animation without keyframes

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I have to develop a css template, with animation in @-webkit-keyframes, in an online auction site for a client. The problem is, when I write my css in , the auction service adds something like @user-field in front of every declaration, so : .topMenu { styles; styles; } becomes #user-field .topMenu {styles; styles; }

And the thing is, when you add something like #user-field in front of @-webkit-keyframes declaration, it just stops to work. So, my question is: Can i make the same effects, by wrapping the '@-webkit.... ' in any tag? Or can I put all my stops (the 20%, 50% etc. ) directly in animation:{} ?

Comment: What kind of animation do you need? Would a scaled back version in CSS3 transitions not be enough?

Comment: No, there is no wrap and the `@` is necessary. An alternate solution would require using javascript or another means to achieve the same effect